# How to use FileReader in Javascript with own path?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Application. In an `<select>` I display different .txt files. When i choose an `<option>` and click on a button i get the path of this file. Now I want to read this file with the FileReader, but i do not really know how to get this path into the FileReader.

```
$('#selectFile').on('click', getSelectedFile);

    function getSelectedFile() {
        var e = document.getElementById("selectFiles");
        var path = e.options[e.selectedIndex].id;
        console.log(path);
    }
```

Output of

`console.log: C:\FilesToWatch\abc.txt`

Thanks in advance for your tips!

Comment: Where is this file, is it on your server or on the user's system ?

Comment: @Titus at the moment at the user's system, but in the later versions of my program it will be on a server

Comment: In that case, the user has to upload the file through an `<input type="file" />` element.

Comment: @Titus but i do not want the user to upload the file by himself. Is there no other way to get the text of a .txt file just with the path in js?

Comment: No, you cannot do that and that is a good thing. Imagine if all websites will be able to access your file system.

Comment: "in the later versions of my program it will be on a server" ...in that scenario you wouldn't use FileReader or input elements to get it, you'd just load it from the server (either by injecting into the page at creation time in a server-side script, or by using AJAX during the page's execution).